# Physics package does not load with MathJax on test web page

Tags: html, configuration, mathjax

I have created this simple `html` file to test various configurations for `MathJax`. In this example the file loads the latest version of `MathJax` with a configuration file
`TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML` from a cdn. The inline configuration loads the `physics` package:

```
<head>
    <title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]},
        TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } },
        loader: {load: ['[tex]/physics']},
        tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['physics']}},
        "HTML-CSS": {
          fonts: ["TeX"],
        }
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>
    <!---->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide|Sofia|Tai+Heritage+Pro|Trykker|Tiro+Telugu|Vesper+Libre|Brawler|Georama|Fjord+One|Trirong|Fresca|Anonymous+Pro|Baskervville">
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'Baskervville', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
    \begin{equation}
    \color{red}{x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}}.  
    \end{equation}
    For some reason I use $ \qty[ c ] $...
</body>
```

The output is:

[image]
By the way I have tried using `\require{physics}` but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing MathJax v2 and v3 configuration styles and still linking to the long retired mathjax CDN.

The physics package is only available with MathJax v3. The following matches your configuration.

```html
<script>
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {
    load: ['[tex]/physics']
  },
  tex: { 
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
    tags: 'ams',
    packages: {'[+]': ['physics']}
  } 
};

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>

  $\qty[c]$ etc.

\begin{equation}
 \acosecant x 
\end{equation}
```

Some references:

- https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html#using-mathjax-from-a-content-delivery-network-cdn
- https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html#configuring-mathjax
- https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/eqnumbers.html#automatic-equation-numbering
- https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/physics.html

Comment: Many thanks for answering a beginners question.

Comment: No worries at all. The long history of v2 means it is still quite confusing sometimes. The upcoming v4 won't be such a complete change in the APIs luckily.